# Datatype promotion for dependently challenged

Tags: haskell, types, language-design, dependent-type

After reading through the ghc 7.4. pre-release notes and the [Giving Haskell a Promotion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/fc-kind-poly.pdf) paper, I'm still confused on what you actually do with promoted types. For example, the GHC manual gives the following examples on promoted datatypes:

```
data Nat = Ze | Su Nat

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

data Pair a b = Pair a b

data Sum a b = L a | R b
```

What kind of uses do these have as kinds? Can you give (code) examples?

Comment: This is a good question. One way to construct a good answer might be to translate the example files you get when you "cabal install she". I could post SHE-code, as an exercise for the reader: would that be useful? I'm trying to install 7.4 just now, but I'm running Leopard and I fear a bad outcome.

Comment: @pigworker, I tried to take a look at SHE examples and I think I grokked some parts, but a simple SHE example with bit of "comments for dummies" would probably be nice also.

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two examples in the paper itself:

"1. Introduction" says: "for example, we might be able to ensure [at compile time] that an alleged red-black tree really has the red-black property".

"2.1 Promoting datatypes" discusses length-indexed vectors (that is, vectors with compile-time "index out of bounds" errors).

You can also take a look at earlier work in this direction, e.g. HList library for type-safe heterogenous lists and extensible collections. [Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html) has many related works. You can also read works on programming with dependent types. http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/ssgip/main.pdf has introductory examples for type-level computations in Agda, but those can be applied to Haskell as well.

Roughly, the idea is that `head` for lists is given a more precise type. Instead of

```
head :: List a -> a
```

it is

```
head :: NotEmptyList a -> a
```

The latter head function is more typesafe than the fomer: it can never be applied to empty lists because it would cause compiler errors.

You need type-level computations to express types such as NotEmptyList. Type classes with functional dependencies, GAGTs and (indexed) type families already provide weak forms of type-level computations for haskell. The work you mentioned just elaborates further in this direction.

See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Non-empty_list for an implementation using only Haskell98 type classes.

Comment: I would very much like to see the red-black tree example.

Comment: Could you expand a bit why you need type level computations for NotEmptyList type? Atleast the wiki page you mention does nothing at the type level.

Answer (score 2):

`Nat` can be e.g. used to construct numerical vectors that can be only added if they have the same length, checked at **compile time**.