# Dependently typed queue in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type

I tried to answer my own question about [examples using the PolyKinds extension in GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600692/datatype-promotion-for-dependently-challenged), and came up with a more concrete problem. I'm trying to model a queue that is build out of two lists, the head-list where the `dequeue` takes elements from, and the tail-list where the `enqueue` puts them. 
To make this interesting, I decided to add a constraint that the tail list cannot be longer than the head list.

It seems that `enqueue` must return different types if the queue should be balanced or not.
Is it at all possible to give proper type for the `enqueue` function with this constraint?

The code that I currently have is here:

```
{-#LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances,
    UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, GADTs,
    RankNTypes#-}

-- Queue consist of a head and tail lists with the invariant that the
-- tail list should never grow longer than the head list.

-- Type for representing the invariant of the queue
data MyConstraint = Constraint Nat Nat
type family Valid c :: Bool
type instance Valid (Constraint a b) = GE a b 

-- The queue type. Should the constraint be here?
data Queue :: * -> MyConstraint -> * where
  Empty :: Queue a (Constraint Zero Zero)
  NonEmpty :: Valid (Constraint n m) ~ True => 
          LenList a n -> LenList a m -> Queue a (Constraint n m) 

instance (Show a) => Show (Queue a c) where
  show Empty = "Empty"
  show (NonEmpty a b) = "NonEmpty "++quote a ++ " " ++ quote b

quote a = "("++show a++")"

-- Check the head of the queue
peek :: GE m (Succ Zero) ~ True => Queue a (Constraint m n) -> a
peek (NonEmpty (CONS a _) _) = a

-- Add an element to the queue where head is shorter than the tail
push :: (Valid (Constraint m (Succ n))) ~ True =>  
        a -> Queue a (Constraint m n) -> Queue a (Constraint m (Succ n))
push x (NonEmpty hd as) = NonEmpty hd (CONS x as)

-- Create a single element queue
singleton :: (Valid (Constraint (Succ Zero) Zero)) ~ True =>  
        a -> Queue a (Constraint (Succ Zero) Zero) 
singleton x = NonEmpty (CONS x NIL) NIL

-- Reset the queue by reversing the tail list and appending it to the head list
reset :: (Valid (Constraint (Plus m n) Zero)) ~ True =>
      Queue a (Constraint m n) -> Queue a (Constraint (Plus m n) Zero)
reset Empty = Empty
reset (NonEmpty a b) = NonEmpty (cat a b) NIL -- Should have a reverse here

enqueue :: ?? 
enqueue = -- If the tail is longer than head, `reset` and then `push`, otherwise just `push`
```

The auxiliary type level lists and nats are defined below.

```
-- Type Level natural numbers and operations

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

type family Plus m n :: Nat
type instance Plus Zero n = n
type instance Plus n Zero = n
type instance Plus (Succ m) n = Succ (Plus m n)

type family GE m n :: Bool
type instance GE (Succ m) Zero = True
type instance GE Zero (Succ m) = False
type instance GE Zero  Zero = True
type instance GE (Succ m) (Succ n) = GE m n

type family EQ m n :: Bool
type instance EQ Zero Zero = True
type instance EQ Zero (Succ m) = False
type instance EQ (Succ m) Zero = False
type instance EQ (Succ m) (Succ n) = EQ m n

-- Lists with statically typed lengths
data LenList :: * -> Nat -> * where
  NIL :: LenList a Zero
  CONS :: a -> LenList a n -> LenList a (Succ n)

instance (Show a) => Show (LenList a c) where
  show x = "LenList " ++ (show . toList $ x)

-- Convert to ordinary list
toList :: forall a. forall m. LenList a m -> [a]
toList NIL = []
toList (CONS a b) = a:toList b

-- Concatenate two lists
cat :: LenList a n -> LenList a m -> LenList a (Plus n m)
cat NIL a = a
cat a   NIL = a
cat (CONS a b) cs = CONS a (cat b cs)
```

Comment: Ask yourself what you want the type of Queues to tell you. Do you want to maintain the invariant (between the lists) internally? Do you want to expose the length of the queue? You may also want to consider storing the witness to the difference in list lengths, which will decrease to zero as you enqueue, telling you easily which policy to choose and when to rebalance.

Answer (score 5):

Following Pigworkers hints I managed to cobble up the following bit of code. I added a flag that the queue needs to be reset to the constraint and used that to dispatch the call to proper version of `enqueue`.

The result is a bit verbose and I'm still looking for better answers or improvements on this. 
(I'm not even really sure that I managed to cover all of the invariant breaking cases with the constraints.)

```
-- Type for representing the invariant of the queue
data MyConstraint = Constraint Nat Nat Bool
type family Valid c :: Bool
type instance Valid (Constraint a b c) = GE a b 

type family MkConstraint m n :: MyConstraint
type instance MkConstraint m n = Constraint m n (EQ m n)

-- The queue type. Should the constraint be here?
data Queue :: * -> MyConstraint -> * where
  Empty :: Queue a (MkConstraint Zero Zero)
  NonEmpty :: --Valid (Constraint n m True) ~ True => -- Should I have this here?
          LenList a n -> LenList a m -> Queue a (MkConstraint n m) 

instance (Show a) => Show (Queue a c) where
  show Empty = "Empty"
  show (NonEmpty a b) = "NonEmpty "++quote a ++ " " ++ quote b

quote a = "("++show a++")"

-- Check the head of the queue
peek :: GE m (Succ Zero) ~ True => Queue a (Constraint m n f) -> a
peek (NonEmpty (CONS a _) _) = a

-- Since the only way to dispatch using the type seems to be a typeclass,
-- and enqueue must behave differently with different constraint-types it follows
-- that the enqueue needs to be in a typeclass?
class Enqueue a where
  type Elem a :: *
  type Next a :: *
  -- Add an element to the queue where head is shorter than the tail
  enqueue :: Elem a -> a -> Next a

-- Enqueuing when the queue doesn't need resetting.
instance Enqueue (Queue a (Constraint m n False)) where
  type Elem (Queue a (Constraint m n False)) = a
  type Next (Queue a (Constraint m n False)) = 
        (Queue a (MkConstraint m (Succ n))) 
  enqueue x (NonEmpty hd as) = NonEmpty hd (CONS x as)

-- Enqueuing when the queue needs to be reset.
instance Enqueue (Queue a (Constraint m n True)) where
  type Elem (Queue a (Constraint m n True)) = a
  type Next (Queue a (Constraint m n True)) = 
        Queue a (MkConstraint (Plus m (Succ n)) Zero)
  enqueue x Empty = NonEmpty (CONS x NIL) NIL 
  enqueue x (NonEmpty hd tl) = NonEmpty (cat hd (CONS x tl)) NIL 
                  -- Should have a reverse tl here. Omitted for
                  -- brevity.
```